# Cryptic "Invalid shorthand property initializer" error message, trying to pass a POST through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, last.fm

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting this error (but I am also fairly new to javascript). Can anyone help?

Error shows up on line 29 supposedly, but it looks right to me.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        window.alert('ok!');
        var url = $(location).attr('href');
        window.alert(url);
        var afterEqual = url.substr(url.indexOf("=") + 1);
        window.alert(afterEqual);
        var token = afterEqual;
        if (token.length > 0) {
            window.alert("performing signature!");
            var sig = "api_key7b42da46777d0daaca78ca34ee93fa1dmethodaugh.getSessiontoken" + token + "21bc1ff066955de8f38ccd55a62d5738";
            var api_signature = md5(sig);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
                data = "method=" + "auth.getSession"+ "&api_key=" + "7b42da46777d0daaca78ca34ee93fa1d" + "&token=" + token + "&api_sig=" + api_signature,
                success: function(xcode){
                    window.alert("Congratulations! You are permanently logged in now!");
                    var xml = $.parseXML(xcode),
                    $xml = $( xml ),
                    $name = $xml.find("name");

                    $( "#loginStatus" ).append("you are now logged in as:" ).append($name.text() );
                }
            });
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Pasted on JSFiddle, console told me error in line where `url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/`. And that's right, you are using variable assignment operador `=`, instead of object key-value operator `:` in few lines. You also missed a `)` in the final line -> `});`. Fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/wqhf7cuy/